# Python if print doesn't show anything after i run it

Tags: python

I want this code to show me one of those 2 answears after the user typed one of them but after i type yes or no, i get nothing in return??

```
while True:
    answear = input("text to be added")

    if answear in ["yes", "no", "Yes", "No"]:
        break

if answear == ["yes", "Yes"]:
    print("answear 1")

elif answear == ["no", "No"]:
    print("answear 2")
```

Thanks

Comment: You already did it correctly inside the loop.

Comment: By the way, it’s spelled "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string to a list `["yes","Yes"]` which will always evaluate to false, and since you didn't specify the `else` condition, you will get nothing as an output.

You can fix this issue by using the word `in` which can be used to evaluate individual elements in a list:

```
if answear in ["yes", "Yes"]:
    print("answear 1")

elif answear in ["no", "No"]:
    print("answear 2")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [61]: while True:
    ...:     answear = input("text to be added")
    ...:
    ...:     if answear.lower() in ["yes", "no"]:
    ...:         break
    ...:
    ...: if answear.lower() == "yes":
    ...:     print("answear 1")
    ...:
    ...: elif answear.lower() == "no":
    ...:     print("answear 2")
```

A better way to do is to convert the answear to lowercase and check

Answer (score -2):

After the while loop, you need to check

```
if answear in ["Yes","yes"]:
    print('answer 1')
```

instead of checking for equality `answear == ["Yes", "yes"]`.